# Are rational functions a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, rational-functions

Let $\mathscr P_n[x]$ be the space of real polynomials in $x\in\mathbb R$ of degree at most $n\in\mathbb N$, and $$\mathscr P[x] := \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathscr P_n[x]$$ the set of all real polynomials in $x$.

Then consider the set $V$ whose elements $v(x)$ are defined by $$v(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \qquad \text{for} \quad p(x), q(x) \in \mathscr P [x],$$ with $q(x) \ne 0$ (the zero function). Is this set a vector space under addition?

My naïve answer would be yes, with a basis of elements of the form $$b(x) = \frac{(x-\hat x^1)(x-\hat x^2)\cdots(x-\hat x^m)} {(x-\hat x_1)(x-\hat x_2)\cdots(x-\hat x_n)} \qquad \hat x^i, \hat x_j \in \mathbb C$$ such that the coefficients of the numerator and denominator are real, but I'm not sure whether I'm neglecting something. It certainly seems to me that both linear independence and spanning should work.

*Bonus:* If it is a vector space, does it have a name?

---

There is a superficially similar question to mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916658/do-rational-functions-form-a-vector-space), but that one is asking for *fixed* $q(x)$ only.

---

Edits: courtesy of comments, have changed slightly the definitions of $q(x)$ and $b(x)$.

Comment: You probably meant to define $v(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \text{ for } p(x), q(x) \in \mathscr P [x] \color{red}{ \text{ with } q(x)\ne 0}$

Comment: The elements you propose are far from been a basis. How will you write the polynomial $x^2+1$ as a linear combination of those elements?

Comment: It is a vector space, but your basis is wrong. The roots do not need to be real, and your $b(x)$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: The name is the rational functions in $x$ over the reals: usual notation is $\mathbb R(x)$.

Comment: What does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathscr P_n[x]$ mean? Perhaps you mean $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \mathscr P_n[x]$

Comment: The real rational functions are the field of fractions of real polynomials. Since it's a field it's a vector space over itself in the same way $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over itself.

Comment: @Jair A quick search on Wikipedia suggested that for sequences of sets $U_i$ where $U_i \subseteq U_j \ \ \forall i \leq j$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n$ exists and is equal to $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} U_n$, as you say.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the symbol (do you have a link to any resource that uses it?).  As for linear independence, would it be enough to keep the general structure of my $b(x)$ and add some clever constraints on the numerator/denominator polynomials?

Comment: You can get a basis by considering [partial fraction decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting together everything from the comments:

1. Given an arbitrary real polynomial quotient $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ $\left(P(x), Q(x) \in \mathscr P[x]\right)$, you can uniquely decompose it into basis functions by

   1. applying the method of long division, to obtain $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = R(x) + \frac{\bar P(x)}{Q(x)},$$ where $R(x), \bar P(x)\in \mathscr P[x]$ with $\operatorname{deg} \bar P < \operatorname {deg} Q,$ then
   2. exploiting the [unique decomposition via partial fractions](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rational_function) of $\frac{\bar P(x)}{Q(x)}$ to write $$\frac{\bar P(x)}{Q(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^r \left[
      \frac{c_{i_{1}}}{x - b_{i}} + \dots + 
      \frac{c_{i_{l_i}}}{(x - b_{i})^{l _ {i}}}\right] +
      \sum _ { j=1}^s  \left [ \frac{d _ {j _ {1}  } x + e _ {j _ {1}  } }{x  ^ {2} + p _ {j} x + q _ {j} }
       + \dots +
      \frac{d _ {j _ { t _ j }  } x + e _ {j _ { t _ j }  } }{( x  ^ {2} + p _ {j} x + q _ {j} ) ^ {t _ {j} } }
       \right ] ,$$ for some coefficients $c, d, e \in\mathbb R$ to be determined.

   This holds for any $Q(x)$, which has been here maximally factorised in the reals to the form $$Q(x) = b _ {0} ( x - b _ {1} ) ^ {l _ {1} } \cdots ( x - b _ {r} ) ^ {l _ {r} } ( x  ^ {2} + p _ {1} x + q _ {1} ) ^ {t _ {1} } \cdots
   ( x  ^ {2} + p _ {s} x + q _ {s} ) ^ {t _ {s} } .$$

   This decomposition (exists, unique) means that we have a set of (spanning, independent) basis vectors $$1, x^u, \frac{1}{(x-b)^l}, \frac{1}{(x^2+px+q)^t}$$ with $u,l,t \in \mathbb N_*$ and $b, p, q \in \mathbb R_*$ (and $p^2 - 4q <0$).

   Hence, it is a vector space.
2. Apparently the vector space is called *the rational functions in $x$ on the reals* and denoted $\mathbb R (x)$, but I can't find any reference for that. (@Robert Israel)
3. More than a vector space, $\mathbb R (x)$ is actually a field, because it has multiplicative structure (see the answer by @Jos).

Thank you to everyone who contributed to sorting this out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Abstract_algebra_and_geometric_notion uses the same notation for the rational function field, for example. It's pretty standard in algebra, I haven't seen any other symbol at least.

Answer (score 1):

Since the vector space requirements are met you can say they form a vector space. But you can make the stronger claim that they are a field, since you can multiply them with each other, and they have (except for the zero element) a multiplicative inverse, the latter by just exchanging $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Waiting before accepting, to give people a chance to resolve the issues raised in comments.